# (Python) Having problems with IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python

Ok, so I've been developing this code to open `File1` to extract the first column of it and paste it into the first column of `File2`. So far I believe my code as it is coded would work, but for some reason, my `File1` isn't reading. I keep getting this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Data_reader_project_(HARBOR)\\TestFilesForAlan-Aerostat160215\\Aerostat160215\\AtmoSniffer160215\\dyn_0'
```

I have checked the paths and they seem to exist, my parent directory also exists.

Here is my code:

```
 File1= 'C:\Data_reader_project_(HARBOR)\TestFilesForAlan-Aerostat160215\Aerostat160215\AtmoSniffer160215\dyn_0'

 File2 = 'C:\Data_reader_project_(HARBOR)\TestFilesForAlan-Aerostat160215\Aerostat160215\HiSAM1_data_160215_164858'


with open(File1,'r') as file1, open(File2,'w') as file2:
    for line in file1:
       x=line.split()
       file2.write('\n',join((x[0],x[0]))+'\n')
```

I've made sure that in both of my file paths there isn't anything like `I like apples`, I know that would make python to not detect my path, so in my file path I have everything like this `I_like_apples'. Nonetheless, other than this potential bug I can't think of anything else.

Any input would help.

Comment: What's the full traceback? And what are the full paths you're trying to access?

Comment: The error `No such file or directory` means the file doesn't exist ;-) Make sure the paths are correct! Also make sure the parent directory exists.

Comment: You could try grabbing it from os.listdir()

Comment: @carpetsmoker this is the path for file2   "C:\\Users\\Alan\\Desktop\\Data_reader_project_(HARBOR)\\TestFilesForAlan-Aerostat160215\\Aerostat160215\\AtmoSniffer160215\\dyn_0"

Comment: I can't check if that paths exists. It's your computer. I don't have access to it. Only you can check that. You should also [edit] this information in the question, and not put it in the comments.

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit this is the full trace back for both files

File1= 'C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\Data_reader_project_(HARBOR)\TestFilesForAlan-Aerostat160215\Aerostat160215\AtmoSniffer160215\dyn_0'

File2 = 'C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\Data_reader_project_(HARBOR)\TestFilesForAlan-Aerostat160215\Aerostat160215\HiSAM1_data_160215_164858'

Comment: @Carpetsmoker sorry about the editing, but I have checked the paths and they seem to exist, my parent directory also exist, i know because for FIle1 the program does not give me an error.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Can you put all of this information and the full error message output in the original question with formatting?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think I have formtted the question better this time. Please let me know if it needs improvement, I am pulling my hair and I can't think of a reason why my paths aren't working.

Comment: Do you check the extension name of the file? I mean in windows `abc.txt` may just show as `abc` with the extension hided, it depends on your setting of File Explorer.

Comment: BTW, in case you don't know, you may use raw string to avoid things like \\. Try  `print('\n')` and `print(r'\n')` . The difference comes from the leading `r`.

Comment: @Syrtis you were right it was the extension name I realized i had to put .csv at the end. However, I had to redo the entire code because I was still not reading my path name, the other thing that I found out was the instead i had to use / dashes in my file path. That did it once i re do my code. Now i can read one file, next step is to get the first column of the file and paste it into a second .csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 File1= 'C:\\Data_reader_project_(HARBOR)\\TestFilesForAlan-Aerostat160215\\Aerostat160215\\AtmoSniffer160215\\dyn_0'

 File2 = 'C:\\Data_reader_project_(HARBOR)\\TestFilesForAlan-Aerostat160215\\Aerostat160215\\HiSAM1_data_160215_164858'
```

or

```
File1= 'C:/Data_reader_project_(HARBOR)/TestFilesForAlan-Aerostat160215/Aerostat160215/AtmoSniffer160215/dyn_0'

File2 = 'C:/Data_reader_project_(HARBOR)/TestFilesForAlan-Aerostat160215/Aerostat160215/HiSAM1_data_160215_164858'
```

Comment: What if you copy one of the files to your desktop, right click the file after it's been copied, copy the new path that windows shows you and paste that into your python script?

Comment: @Yunhe I've tried that and nothing, but i think i know what the problem is, but please give me some input if you agree. Since I am trying to open a spreadsheet that is saved as .cvs file python won't read it because i don't have csv imported. However, now that I've checked the problem still the same... HAHA